# In Halmos' Naive Set Theory, how can there be more than 1 successor set?

Tags: set-theory

The axiom of infinity clearly states that there exists a set $A$ containing $0$ and the successor of its elements.

Shortly after introducing this axiom, Halmos goes to say:

> Since the intersection of every non-empty family of successor **sets** is a successor set itself...

But by the axiom we're only guaranteed one successor set - $A$. How can we then have a **family** of the same repeated set?

Edit:

Recently today I asked a question which I since deleted about the definition of successor sets. Mainly - Halmos defines the successor set:

> We shall say, temporarily, that a set $A$ is a successor set if $0 \in A$ and if $x^+ \in A$ whenever $x \in A$

This gave me the illusion that there's only **one** such set.

Comment: The existence of a successor set $A$ is enough for the existence of a non-empty family of successor sets: $\{A\}$.

Comment: @drhab true. But what about the reference to successor sets?

Comment: A family of successor sets could also only contain one successor set. The use of the plural here is grammatical, not mathematical.

Comment: On base of your edit I conclude things are clear now for you. Your illusion turned out to be a delusion.

Comment: @drhab Well, I have no other straws to grasp from the given definition. I'm not sure how it's a delusion then.

Comment: The definition does not suggest anywhere that there is only one successor set. So making that conclusion is just wrong.

Comment: @drhab It doesn't suggest there are any others either.

Comment: It does not have to. It only tells when a set can be called a successor set. That is just enough for a definition of a successor set. That's how it works in mathematics.

Comment: @drhab I think I get it now - by the axiom you have one successor set. Through previous axioms you can construct more sets that happen to also adhere... and those successor sets might consist of "starting points" other than $0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are, in fact, lots of successor sets.  Start with any set $B$, then
$$
A \cup \{B, B^+, B^{++}, B^{+++}, \dots\}
$$
is a successor set.  You are correct that the axiom guarantees only one successor set.  But it leaves the possiblity open of whether there are many of them.

Comment: So in other words, the definition given by Halmos for a successor set is not an "exhaustive" definition?

Comment: Halmos tells you a definition.  "A set $A$ is a **successor set** if ..."  Of course that definition does not claim there is only one of them.  Compare this:  "A triangle $\Delta$ is an **isosceles triangle** if ... "  This is the defintion, and there could possibly be more than one isosceles triangle.

Comment: I have to disagree. If I never tell you what constitutes an isosceles triangle, I can just call something an isosceles triangle and you will not be able to extrapolate the definition.

Comment: You can watch 2 players play chess ten million times and you'll never be sure if you got the rules of chess right. Edit: Chess is a "bad" example since there's a finite amount of games... but I hope you get the point.

Comment: Finally things started clicking :)

Comment: @Threnody: Your example of the isosceles triangle is irrelevant, because Halmos **does** tell you what constitutes a successor set. It is any set that contains $0$ and contains the successor of each of its members.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott yep, I see it now,  your written example is very helpful.